# Cannot send an email from Azure Automation Account

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

Have tried to send an email from Azure.

```
$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'email@contoso.com'

$Username = $Credential.Username

$Password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

 

[securestring]$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force

[pscredential]$PSCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username, $SecurePassword)

 

$Username

$Password
```

[PS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA1ca.png)

But, I am getting this error. Have tried to Google, but no real solution or explanation that I could find. Maybe some of you have been close with this one?

Error that we are getting is:

```
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server

response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

[AM7PR03CA0008.eurprd03.prod.outlook.com]

At line:26 char:1

+ Send-MailMessage @mailParams

+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage],

SmtpException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Also.. you need to post your code. We don't know whether your code tries to authenticate or not

Comment: There are two excellent links here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c82a50ee-ddf8-4db2-93d9-0c2bf630a516/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated-the-server?forum=azureautomation

Comment: Ok, seems that this one could be accomplished only with legacy authentication enabled. Is there any other possibility like app password?

Comment: Also I have tried with https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Sending-email-from-Azure-24ee27cd but I see that workflow is not supported in PS 6+

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid updated the code with authentication. There was no problem with that. But the problem is sending an email.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  According to my test, we can use the script(https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Sending-email-from-Azure-24ee27cd) to send email in Azure runbook : https://ibb.co/DVvkHF1

Comment: _workflow is not supported in PS 6_ I don't think that is relevant here. @JimXu appears to have tested it OK.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You can PowerShell script runbook. It is ok.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you. Now @tonnydarko needs to try it

Comment: Will do gentleman. Thank you! :)